# How can I create thumbnails of pdfs with node.js and gm

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, meteor, graphicsmagick

I'm using meteor(which is built on node) and CollectionCFS(which allows me to use gm[GraphicsMagick] for thumb-nailing).

I do the following to have it automaticly create a thumbnail of uploaded images:

```
new FS.Store.FileSystem("thumbs", {
      transformWrite: function(fileObj, readStream, writeStream) {
        gm(readStream, fileObj.name()).resize('100', '100').stream().pipe(writeStream);
      },
      path: "/Volumes/Public/Thumbs",
    })
```

The transformWrite function receives the readStream(the original image), modifies it and pipes the results to the writeStream.  How could I have it create thumbnails of PDF's?

Comment: Did you try this code with a PDF file? As far as I can tell, it should work. Maybe add "png" as an argument to stream()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want the pdf's first page as thumbnail. do the following:

```
new FS.Store.FileSystem("thumbs", {
  transformWrite: function(fileObj, readStream, writeStream) {
    gm(readStream, fileObj.name() + '[0]').resize('100', '100').stream('png').pipe(writeStream);
  },
  beforeWrite: function (fileObj) {
    return {
      extension: 'png',
      type: 'image/png'
    };
  },
  path: "/Volumes/Public/Thumbs",
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much for working on this question.  I was very excited to try this out!  This solution creates the thumbnail perfectly, but for some reason the urls never seem to work. Are you sure about the fileObj.name()+'[0]' part?

Comment: I tried fileObj.name, and slugify(fileObj.name) and I also just tried moving this logic to the beforeWrite like this:  name:slugify(fileObj.name),  but none of it seems to work.  The file is there, but the url generated doesn't seem to match

Comment: I seem to be wrong.  The images look ok in dropbox (I'm using cfs:dropbox) but when I download them, they're corrupted.  I noticed that if I upload an image, the thumbnail is made and displayed correctly.  So apparently the PDF's thumbnail is not quite right.

Comment: That's it! It worked! Thanks a ton! I'd never have figured that one out.